# Knockout Validation & Proper way to clear controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the following code and it works fine, **EXCEPT** when you clear the property after you have inserted an item. The error shows up right away.

```
ko.validation.configure({
        insertMessages: false,
        decorateElement: true,
        errorElementClass: 'error'
    });

FirstName: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true
        }),
```

and I have add method in the knockout viewmodel

```
addItem: function () {
            if (!viewModel.isValid()) {
                viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
                return false;
            } else {
                //DO SOMETHING
                this.SomeCollection.push(newInterviewee);
                this.FirstName(null);
                }
        },
```

I have the following in the HTML:

```
<div>
<label>First Name</label>
<input data-bind="value: FirstName, validationElement: FirstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" class="input" type="text">
</div>
<div>
<div>
<input data-bind="click: addItem" class="button" type="button">
</div>
```

The problem is that after I call this.FirstName(null). The error shows up right away! I want the error to show up only when they press the button even after the property is cleared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that is provided by Steve Greatrex: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/210

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on our project. We solved this by forcing isValid to true.

```
addItem: function () {
            if (!viewModel.isValid()) {
                viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
                return false;
            } else {
                //DO SOMETHING
                this.SomeCollection.push(newInterviewee);
                this.FirstName(null);
                viewModel.isValid(true);
            }
        },
```

To be able to do this, you need to overwrite ko.validation's definition for the isValid computed as follows:

```
observable.isValid = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return observable.__valid__();
    },
        write: observable.__valid__
    }
);
```

Comment: hmm. i am getting this error when i call the viewMOdel.isValid(true); Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.

Comment: Yeah I got the same problem, I'll have to look it up in our code and will edit my answer today

Comment: I see you found a better solution. Ours was to overwrite the isValid to include a write statement. I have added this in my answer

Comment: Yeah I just went straight to the source and asked for a proper solution. Those guys were very helpful.